# ZF2 - Error Handling for a Specific Module Only

Tags: php, error-handling, zend-framework2, zend-framework-modules

I have a multi-modular app.

And one of its modules listens to "dispatch.error" with 999 priority. And it appears to catch errors from all other modules.

What I need is to catch error **in my specific module only** and behave appropriately. It will work if I for example will listen to "dispatch.error" with 1000 priority and filter out errors specific to my module (by exception names or using route filtering), but there's no guarantee that some other module won't come with 10000 priority for the same event.

I'm pretty new to ZF2 and don't know if there's a proper way to solve this.

It looks like this question about the same: [ZF2: How to attach module specific listener for dispatch.error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17948543/zf2-how-to-attach-module-specific-listener-for-dispatch-error), but the response does not help at all though it is accepted.

**Update:**
I found out, that it could be fixed by changing `DispatchListener.php` (when using custom ID within `SharedEventManager`).

`DispatchListener` gets `EventManager` like this:

```
$events  = $application->getEventManager();
```

But if controller exists this could be overridden with:

```
$events = $controller->getEventManager();
```

And then the issue with module-specific error handlers would be solved.

Does anyone know solutions without fixing of core files? And is it actually a bug (that custom module can listen to "dispatch" for example, but cannot listen to "dispatch.error")

Comment: You meant you want to find thet error in that particular module right?

Comment: Yes, catch errors in a specific module only. It looks like it should be possible to do using sharedEventManager, but does not work for some reason.

Comment: Try with this answer code https://stackoverflow.com/a/38880985/4511459 I research about dispatch error, in zf2 book also this code to find that error

Comment: @Nawin it won't help unfortunately, dispatch event happens before errors being thrown.

Comment: may be you can check the name of controller with event, so you will know which module. if you found your module you may handle those error only

Comment: @ShahadatHossainKhan yes, you're right, I did it this way. It seems that there's no build-in possibility to do this